# Regex optimization and best practice

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-lookarounds, regex-group, regex-greedy

I need to parse information out from a legacy interface. We do not have the ability to update the legacy message. I'm not very proficient at regular expressions, but I managed to write one that does what I want it to do. I just need peer-review and feedback to make sure it's clean.

The message from the legacy system returns values resembling the example below.

```
%name0=value
%name1=value
%name2=value
```

```
Expression: /\%(.*)\=(.*)/g;
```

```
var strBody = body_text.toString();
var myRegexp = /\%(.*)\=(.*)/g;
var match = myRegexp.exec(strBody);
var objPair = {};

while (match != null) {
    if (match[1]) {
        objPair[match[1].toLowerCase()] = match[2];
    }
    match = myRegexp.exec(strBody);
}
```

This code works, and I can add partial matches the middle of the name/values without anything breaking. I have to assume that any combination of characters could appear in the "values" match. Meaning it could have equal and percent signs within the message.

- Is this clean enough?
- Is there something that could break the expression?

Comment: If your code works well and there is no issue, please consider posting the question at [codereview.se].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, don't escape characters that don't need escaping: `%(.*)=(.*)`

The problem with your expression: An equals sign in the value would break your parser. `%name0=val=ue` would result in `name0=val`=`ue` instead of `name0`=`val=ue`.

One possible fix is to make the first repetition lazy by appending a question mark: `%(.*?)=(.*)`

But this is not optimal due to unneeded backtracking. You can do better by using a negated character class: `%([^=]*)=(.*)`

And finally, if empty names should not be allowed, replace the first asterisk with a plus: `%([^=]+)=(.*)`

This is a good resource: [Regex Tutorial - Repetition with Star and Plus](https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html)

Comment: Thank you for your feedback and the tutorial.

Answer (score 2):

Your expression is fine, and wrapping it with two capturing groups is simple to get your desired variables and values.

You likely may not need to escape some chars and it would still work.

You can use [this tool](https://regex101.com/r/fMqh41/1/) and test/edit/modify/change your expressions if you wish:

```
%(.+)=(.+)
```

Since your data is pretty structured, you can also do so with string split and get the same desired outputs, if you want.

#### RegEx Descriptive Graph

This graph shows how the expression would work and you can visualize other expressions in this [link](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24):

[image]

#### JavaScript Test

```js
const regex = /%(.+)=(.+)/gm;
const str = `%name0=value
%name1=value
%name2=value`;
let m;

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
    // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
    if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
        regex.lastIndex++;
    }
    
    // The result can be accessed through the `m`-variable.
    m.forEach((match, groupIndex) => {
        console.log(`Found match, group ${groupIndex}: ${match}`);
    });
}
```

#### Performance Test

This JavaScript snippet shows the performance of that expression using a simple 1-million times `for` loop.

```js
const repeat = 1000000;
const start = Date.now();

for (var i = repeat; i >= 0; i--) {
 const string = '%name0=value';
 const regex = /(%(.+)=(.+))/gm;
 var match = string.replace(regex, "\nGroup #1: $1 \n Group #2: $2 \n Group #3: $3 \n");
}

const end = Date.now() - start;
console.log("YAAAY! \"" + match + "\" is a match  ");
console.log(end / 1000 + " is the runtime of " + repeat + " times benchmark test.  ");
```

Comment: Thank you for your feedback and link to the testing tool.